# PHP Loop Dynamic Variable

Tags: php, loops, variables

I am trying to create a dynamic variable. I have a loop and I want it to loop through the records and create a variable for each record. My code:

```
$ct = 1;
foreach ($record as $rec){
  $var.$ct = $rec['Name'];
  $ct = $ct + 1;
}

echo $var1;
```

When I try to use the above code, it gives me an error saying the `$var1` variable doesn't exist/undefined? Is it possible in PHP to create dynamic variables like the above example. If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `$var`??

Comment: My variable that im setting. The constant portion of the variable. It could be anything $name.$ct

Comment: Use arrays instead.

Comment: why are you not using array??

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Create the variable name as a string, and then assign it:

```
$ct = 1;
foreach( $record as $rec )
{
  $name = 'var'.$ct;
  $$name = $rec['Name'];
  $ct++;
}

echo $var1;
```

It would be much better to create an array, though:

```
$names = [ ];

foreach( $record as $rec )
{
  $names[] = $rec['Name'];
}

echo $names[0];
```

Comment: To be clear: It's not just that arrays are a much better solution to the problem, but also that using variable variables is virtually always the _worst_ solution for anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different syntax with `{}`

```
$ct = 1;

foreach ($record as $rec){
    ${'var' . $ct++} = $rec['Name'];
}

echo $var1;
```

Although isn't it better just to use an array?

[Working fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66d57ab62d6fd1f76f239f7e6fec07eb825ce1ea)

Comment: I am getting undefined variable still when using your syntax. Have you tested this?

Comment: yes I have ;) let me include a fiddle just to prove http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66d57ab62d6fd1f76f239f7e6fec07eb825ce1ea

Answer (score 0):

You can with a double $.

```
    $var = "variable";
    $$var = "test";

    echo $variable;
    //echoes "test"
```

in your example:

```
$ct = 1;
foreach ($record as $rec){
$varname = "var" . $ct;
  $$varname = $rec['Name'];
  $ct = $ct + 1;
}

echo $var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, let me know if it works for you.
I use a prefix with the dynamic variable.

```
$ct = 1;
$prefix = 'var';
foreach ($record as $key=>$rec){
  $temp = $ct;
  $ct = $prefix.$ct;
  $$ct = $rec;
  $ct = $temp + 1;
}

echo $var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using array easily. But if you really want it to be in dyanamic vairable individually, in that case also , I would like to suggest you to get help in array way. This way, you can track you variables.

In the below mentioned way, you event don't need to take a extra variable like $ct. Just an array $var and applying extract method on it after the loop will do the trick.

```
$var = [];

foreach( $record as $k => $rec )
{
 $var['var'.$k] = $rec['Name'];

}

extract($var);

echo $var0; //or $var_1 or $var_2
```